# Preg match does not find the correct string

Tags: php, xml, regex

I have a problem where i have a script that supposed to search an XML file for matching strings. 
Here's my script:

```
   <?php
$file = "klein.xml";
$lines = file($file);
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
{
    echo htmlentities($line);
    echo "<br>";

}

   if (preg_match("/message/", htmlentities($line), $found))
   {
     echo "Found!";
     echo $found[0]; 
     echo "test";
   }
   else
   {
       echo "Not Found!";
   }
?>
```

and this is the xml file im working with:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<product-data>
<message-header>
<message-id>OR-1361163557-gr</message-id>
<message-timestamp>1361163557</message-timestamp>
<export-version current_version="1">OGPDX-2.01.01</export-version>
</message-header>
</product-data>
```

The problem is when i preg match 'product' it works correctly but when i try to preg match another string i.e 'message' it doesnt work?

Im curious for the solution, thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Doesn't it find all the matches you're expecting? Does it match something you didn't want it to?

Comment: It doesnt find all the matches im expecting

Comment: Which one doesn't it find?

Comment: it does find 'product' but doesnt find anything else

Comment: You can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/class.domdocument) to traverse the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check this code, I noticed that you put the `if` loop outside `foreach`; hence only the last line is executed.

```
<?php
$file = "klein.xml";
$lines = file($file);
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
{
   if (preg_match("/message/", htmlentities($line), $found))
   {
     echo "Found ".$found[0]."<br />";
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your logic: you are only checking the last value of `$line` which is contain `</product-data>`

Answer (score 0):

so what are you searching in? a line of your xml ...
when you are searching "product" (in last line) $line is in last line .

```
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
{
   if (preg_match("/message/", $line , $found))
   {
     echo "Line: $line_num - ".$found[0]." <br>";
   }
}
```